# How will windows7 act on two touchscreens?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

On a PC with Windows7 OS two display ports (1x VGA, 1x DVI) and two RS232 hardwired COM-ports are present. I want to connect two touchscreen displays to this PC.
BUT ... when I touch one screen, I don't want the other screen/application to react on that same coordinate/position.

Does windows7 support the individual control of these two touchscreens?
Or do I need a software application to manage the coordinates of either screen to a specific part of the desktop? (the desktop settings are NOT to copy the main screen, but to extend the desktop to the second screen.)

A single mouse/trackball will be connected by USB as well, but that will act as a normal pointer and can be moved from one to the other display.

Looking forward to receive comments on this.
Allan

Answer (score 2):

All the touchscreens I've ever used come with their own application to set up and calibrate across multiple monitors, etc. As you are stretching the desktop, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most touchscreen hardware devices come with their own software to help sort out calibration and screen allocation issues, etc. They should act as seperate entities while still linked to that one PC.